# Python TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string

Tags: python, typeerror, getattr

I'm working on a Python script that uses the TMDB (The Movie Database) API to fetch movie information. However, I'm encountering a `TypeError` when trying to access the 'id' attribute from the API response. I'm using the TMDBv3 API wrapper in my script.

Here's the relevant code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

## Extracting features of 2020 movies from Wikipedia

link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_films_of_2020"

source = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

tables = soup.find_all('table',class_='wikitable sortable')

len(tables)

type(tables[0])

from io import StringIO

# Assuming 'tables' is a list containing HTML tables

df1 = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(tables[0])))[0]
df2 = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(tables[1])))[0]
df3 = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(tables[2])))[0]

# Replace "1" with '1"'
df4 = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(tables[3]).replace("'1\"\'",'"1"')))[0]

df = df1._append(df2._append(df3._append(df4,ignore_index=True),ignore_index=True),ignore_index=True)

df

df_2020 = df[['Title','Cast and crew']]

df_2020

!pip install tmdbv3api

from tmdbv3api import TMDb
import json
import requests
tmdb = TMDb()
tmdb.api_key = 'API_KEY'

import numpy as np
import requests
from tmdbv3api import Movie

tmdb_movie = Movie()

def get_genre(x):
    genres = []
    result = tmdb_movie.search(x)
    
    if not result or not hasattr(result[0], 'id'):
        return np.NaN
    
    movie_id = result[0].id
    response = requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{}?api_key={}'.format(movie_id, tmdb_movie.api_key))
    data_json = response.json()
    
    if 'genres' in data_json and data_json['genres']:
        genre_str = " " 
        for i in range(0, len(data_json['genres'])):
            genres.append(data_json['genres'][i]['name'])
        
        return genre_str.join(genres)
    
    return np.NaN


df_2020['genres'] = df_2020['Title'].map(lambda x: get_genre(str(x)))
```

```
Error Message: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-ec558471f2dd> in <module>
----> 1 df_2020['genres'] = df_2020['Title'].map(lambda x: get_genre(str(x)))

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   4542         dtype: object
   4543         """
-> 4544         new_values = self._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
   4545         return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index, copy=False).__finalize__(
   4546             self, method="map"

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action, convert)
    921         elif isinstance(arr, ExtensionArray):
    922             # dispatch to ExtensionArray interface
--> 923             new_values = map_array(arr, mapper, na_action=na_action, convert=convert)
    924 
    925         else:

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in map_array(arr, mapper, na_action, convert)
   1814         return lib.map_infer(values, mapper, convert=convert)
   1815     else:
-> 1816         return lib.map_infer_mask(
   1817             values, mapper, mask=isna(values).view(np.uint8), convert=convert
   1818         )

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-56-ec558471f2dd> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df_2020['genres'] = df_2020['Title'].map(lambda x: get_genre(str(x)))

<ipython-input-53-5e28b0f3e7db> in get_genre(x)
      7     if not result:
      8         return np.NaN
----> 9     movie_id = result[0].id
     10     response = requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{}?api_key={}'.format(movie_id,tmdb.api_key))
     11     data_json = response.json()

c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tmdbv3api\as_obj.py in __getitem__(self, key)
     47         return getattr(self, key)
     48     else:
---> 49         return self._obj_list[key]
     50 
     51     def __iter__(self):

TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

I suspect that the structure of the response object might be causing the issue.

- How can I modify the code to handle the `TypeError` and ensure I'm correctly accessing the 'id' attribute from the TMDB API response?
- Are there any additional checks I should perform on the response object to avoid such errors?

Comment: Can you please show the full error traceback?

Comment: Certainly, I have updated the full error traceback

Comment: You're returning either a NaN or a string. Those won't work together in a Series. Turn the NaN into None, that may work, or an empty string; the latter will certainly work.

Comment: I tried turning the Nan into None, but the error remains the same

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to be with the way you're accessing the 'id' attribute from the TMDB API response. Instead of using the `hasattr()` function, you can directly check if the 'id' key exists in the response JSON object.

To avoid the `TypeError` and ensure you're correctly accessing the 'id' attribute, you can modify your code as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

def get_genre(x):
    genres = []
    result = tmdb_movie.search(x)
    
    if not result:
        return np.NaN
    
    if 'id' in result[0]:
        movie_id = result[0]['id']
        response = requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{}?api_key={}'.format(movie_id, tmdb.api_key))
        data_json = response.json()
        
        if 'genres' in data_json and data_json['genres']:
            genre_str = " " 
            for i in range(0, len(data_json['genres'])):
                genres.append(data_json['genres'][i]['name'])
            
            return genre_str.join(genres)
    
    return np.NaN
```

In this updated code, we are checking if 'id' is present in the TMDB API response by using the `in` operator. If it exists, we access it as `result[0]['id']` instead of using the `hasattr()` function.

Similarly, we also add a check for the presence of the 'genres' key in the `data_json` object before accessing its value. This ensures that the code doesn't break if the 'genres' key is missing in the response.

By making these modifications, you should be able to handle the `TypeError` and properly access the 'id' attribute from the TMDB API response.

Comment: I still get the exact same error